# Q: Recurrence relation by Substitution

Tags: algorithm, substitution, recurrence

I have the recurrence relation: `T(n) = c*T (n/3) + (c/2)*n`
for any c

Let T(n) >= n^1.5 be a guess for substitution method.

Comment: Why not using the master theorem?

Comment: Because the aim is to use the substitution method with this being the guess. Believe me if I could use Master I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `T(n) <= n^1.5` is the right path. With that we can have:

`T(n) <= 6 ( n^1.5 / 3^1.5 ) + 3n` = `(6 / 3^1.5)* n^1.5 + 3n`.

`6/3^1.5` is 5.1... but for now let call it `a`. So we have: `a*n^1.5 + 3n`.

We need to prove there is c > 0 that for n0>n `c*n^1.5 > a*n^1.5 + 3n`. first let divided by n: `c*n^0.5 > a*n^0.5 + 3` which yield: `(c-a)*n^0.5 > 3`.

From here it clear that you can choose any `c > a` and  `n > 9` so this will be true.

To summarize: we  got `T(n)` bigger to `T'(n) = (6/3^1.5)*n^1.5 + 3n` and proved that for `c > 6/3^1.5` and `n > 9` the `T(n) < cg(n) where g(n) = n^1.5`

Comment: I'm not sure this makes a difference in the solution but I was trying to use `T(n) >= n^1.5` and you said, "Assuming `T(n) <= n^1.5`" does this make an err in the solution?

Comment: I assume to solve upper bound. If you want lower bound it the same way. lower `T'(n) = a*n^1.5 + 3n` and find c and n such as `T'(n) >= c*n^1.5`